# Same-origin policy workaround using document.domain in Javascript

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I am running into same-origin policy issues in Javascript.  I've read about a workaround for this using the `document.domain` variable, but I cannot get the workaround to work.  The workaround is that you are supposed to be able to set `document.domain` to `'example.com'` so that if you run code from `foo.example.com` it can load data via XHR from `bar.example.com`.

Details on the workaround are here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

My example code -- which doesn't produce the desired results -- is run from a URL like `http://foo.example.com/`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<script>
document.domain = 'example.com';
window.onload = function() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://bar.example.com/';
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            var elem = document.getElementById('result');
            if (req.status == 200) {
                var data = req.responseText;
            } else {
                var data = "Error loading page: " + req.status;
            }
            elem.innerHTML = data;
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
};
</script>
Result:<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output from this code:

```
Result:
Error loading page: 0
```

If I change `url` to `'http://foo.example.com/'`, everything works correctly.  Is there a bug in my example code?

I don't want to use a proxy because they're slower, less efficient, and will increase traffic on our web server.  It'd be really cool if this workaround actually worked. Is this workaround "pie in the sky"?

Answer (score 24):

`document.domain` allows the communication between frames/iframes. Not XHR.

```
<body>
<iframe src="http://bar.example.com/"></iframe>
<script>
    document.domain = 'example.com';
    var ifr = document.getElementsByTagName('IFRAME')[0];
    ifr.onload = function(e){
        //will log the string "BODY" in the console
        console.log(ifr.contentWindow.document.body.tagName);
    };
</script>
</body>
```

If you remove the line with `document.domain`, reading the content of the contentWindow will throw the Same Origin Policy error.

Comment: I tried it. Setting document.domain in chrome return network error. Developers tools told the same origin policy problem.

Comment: Did you try to set `document.domain` to the same value in both the parent domain and the subdomain ? If not, this causes an error.

Comment: I guess It’s because the iframe is completely a different domain.

Comment: yes, the domain must be the same. This is just useful for sub domain/port issues.

Comment: if foo.example.com sets document.domain=example.com would also bar.foo.example.com be able to communicate if it sets document.domain=example.com ?